# Redux: what is the correct way to filter a data array in reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux

i want to filter an array on search SEARCH_TEXT is an on change action
what I'm confused with is how i return the state when the delete key is pressed and the text now becomes empty, i figure i could use initial state in the else statement but my inclination is this is wrong? when i return just state it has all ready been manipulated in the if statement.

simple example.

thanks in advance.

```
const initialState =  ['hello', 'wahhh', 'yo'];

export default function searchSimple(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_TEXT:
      if(action.text.length > 0){
        return state.filter(item =>
          item.startsWith(action.text)
        )
      }
      else {
        return state
      }
```

Comment: looks correct to me. If no text reduces the previous `state` you can just return it

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Remember always that the state is your "source of truth". Be wary of eliminating state on the basis of a temporary filter. Once you do so those items are gone. (The only way to get them back is to reset your state to the initialState, which may not be ideal.)

A better approach is to keep your items list as is, and simply store the search text.

```
const initialState = {
    searchText: '',
    items: [ 'hello', 'wahhh', 'yo' ]
};

export default function searchSimple(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEARCH_TEXT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                searchText: action.text
            });
    }
}
```

Whilst your state won't contain the filtered list, it tells you everything you need to know to construct the filtered list.

Assuming you're using React, your "smart component" can be setup with the following `mapStateToProps()` function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { items, searchText } = state.searchSimple;
    return {
        filteredItems: items.filter((item) => item.startsWith(searchText))
    };
}
```

Should you need this filtered list in more than one place, consider creating a "selector" function, as demonstrated in the Redux shopping cart example.
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/reducers/cart.js

It would look something like this:

```
export function filteredItems(state) {
    const { items, searchText } = state.searchSimple;
    return items.filter((item) => item.startsWith(searchText));
}
```

For a more advanced approach to selectors, check out the reselect library.

https://github.com/rackt/reselect

Comment: What should we do if we want to use the filteredItems to compute more state. For example, if the `filteredItems` were a collection of flashcards, and we want a reducer to select one of the filtered items at random to quiz the user? The filteredItems are derived from the state, but the selected quiz word should still be part of the state. [see example on StackOverflow for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903793/redux-and-reselect-using-derived-data-to-compute-a-part-of-the-state)

Comment: deadlink - https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/reducers/index.js

Answer (score 31):

IMO, the right place to filter data is not directly in the reducers but in the **selectors**.

From redux docs:

[Computing Derived Data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data)

> [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) is a simple library for creating memoized, composable selector functions. Reselect selectors can be used to efficiently compute derived data from the Redux store.

I'm currently using selectors to **filter** and **sort** data.

1. No data repetition in the state. You don't have to store a copy of the filtered items.
2. The same data can be used in different components, each one using a different filter for example.
3. You can combine selector applying many data computations using selector that you already have in the application.
4. If you do right, your selectors will be pure functions, then you can easily test them.
5. Use the same selector in many components.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but by sorting and filtering in your selectors, you won't be able to take advantage of selector's memoization right ? 
Wouldn't it be better to put the filtering functions in a service, the filters values in the store and perform the filtering and sorting in the component ?