# How to handle computed state in redux, such as filtered collection

Tags: redux

I understand that in redux, the entire app's state should be represented by a single object created with reducers. If I'd like to have a sub-collection that is filtered from the main collection of things, should that be created in a reducer, or should that be handled by a component.

To be more specific, if I have a collection of events as the main data structure from the app, and I want to create sub-collections of events for each month based on the month number, should these sub-collections be created through a reducer passing in the month number, or should it be handled by the component representing the monthly events?

Comment: Either or. There's no one right way to do it. It comes down to a design decision. I'd recommend you do it the way that's most comfortable and makes sense to you and your application.

Comment: I usually opt for a very normalized and de-duped store, and do that sort of computed view into the state in the components — unless performance becomes an issue, in which case memoization might help, or moving the calculation into the reducer itself.

Comment: I like the idea of moving the computation off to the view itself as well. However, my concern is that if I need to trigger events for a specific item in the collection, could I still rely on redux's reducer pattern for that?

Comment: I would avoid putting the filtered state in the reducer. If you do this you're probably going to end up either (a) destroying some of your state, making it impossible to reset or re-filter your data, or (b) duplicating a lot of your state,  i.e. multiple sets of lists with the same items - filtered and unfiltered. You might find the following helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003553/redux-what-is-the-correct-way-to-filter-a-data-array-in-reducer

Comment: Thanks @DavidL.Walsh. I'll also check out the selector example and reselect. I saw them but didn't know they directly related to this. Also, I assume that I could have a reducer for an individual item that is unrelated to the root reducer?

Comment: I don't know how that would work, the root reducer is the combination of all reducers.