# React Redux Array Filter to Map

Tags: react-redux

Hello I'm looking to filter my state in my reducer. to display them in a Flatlist.

unfortunately my state is filtered only once.

what's wrong with the reducers.

here is a youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1Y2PtLk-ck

```
const initialState = {
  data: ''
}

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'FETCH_DATA':
      return { ...state, data: payload }
    case 'ORDER':

      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.filter(user => user.dob.age >= payload.minAge && user.dob.age <= payload.maxAge)
          .map(user => user)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Order action #1:

state.data = previous state.data, filtered to only include older people

Order action #2:

state.data = previous state.data (previously filtered to only include older people), filtered again to only include older people and younger people. Results are the same, because only older people (from previous result) are in this dataset now.

[Redux: what is the correct way to filter a data array in reducer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003553/redux-what-is-the-correct-way-to-filter-a-data-array-in-reducer)

https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data

tl;dr

1. Try to keep computed properties (like filtered data) in mapStateToProps functions, not in the reducer
2. If these mapStateToProps functions are reused, might want to look into selectors/reselect library
3. If you're adamant about storing the filtered data in the reducer, use a separate property like `filteredData` instead of `data`, so it is not overwritten

Also, you can remove the .map() after .filter() as it is not doing anything (only returning the same elements that are already there).